# Silverlight support on iPad?

Tags: ios, silverlight, ipad

We have a Silverlight application developed 2 years ago for a construction client for entering timesheets.  They are moving to using iPads and now find that the application does not run on the iPad.

So... is there iOS support for Silverlight at all?  Is there support for a particular version of Silverlight?  Are there plans for support?

Searching on Google, it's unclear whether there is a solution or not.  I'm seeking clarity here.  The posts I see on SO about this are from October 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No,

http://www.theipadguide.com/faq/does-ipad-supportplay-microsoft-silverlight

> No. Mobile Safari on the iPad will not support or play Microsoft
>   Silverlight content. Apple has also restricted the use of Silverlight
>   on the iPhone.
>
> Netflix uses Silverlight to stream video in the watch instantly
>   section of their website.

EDIT: I do believe there are apps out there that will let you run your silverlight application on a server and stream the results to your ipad or iphone.  This of course would require your silverlight app to be very light since its basically streaming a video and going through another server for interactions

Comment: Netflix uses Apple's native player when you're connected with your ipad or iphone

Comment: Hmm.  That is disappointing.  Right now it seems the best option may be to simply use Remote Desktop from the iPad.