# Asp.Net desktop application on IPAD\IPHONE

Tags: asp.net, desktop-application

Can WPF Desktop application run on IPAD\IPHONE? How about Silverlight application?

What is the best technology of asp.net for desktop application compatible with iOS? At least with iPad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight support on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258944/silverlight-support-on-ipad)

Comment: just one part of the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ASP.NET is a web-application platform that runs on a web-server that is used to generate web-pages that are displayed in a web-browser. It is used to run websites. ASP.NET is absolutely unrelated to desktop or iOS applications.
- WPF is a UI framework that runs on top of the .NET Framework. WPF is heavily tied into Microsoft Windows. It is not available for any other platform.
- Silverlight is a cut down, 2D-only, version of WPF that is mainly used to build browser applets, and nowadays, Windows Phone 7 applications. It officially be used to target Windows, Windows Phone, OS X, and Linux (with Moonlight). It is not supported on iOS, either in the browser or as a means of developing an application.
- iOS applications are not "desktop applications" - a desktop application implies that it presents itself to the user as a non-exclusive, non-fullscreen window and accepts user-input primarily through mouse and keyboard, whereas an iOS application runs full-screen and accepts touch input or from a virtual keyboard.
- To develop for iOS, you must use an Apple-approved language and framework: officially this is C, C++ or Objective-C. (Generally speaking) applications that are not games must (ultimately) use Cocoa Touch for their user-interfaces in order to be consistent with the platform. Wrappers around Cocoa Touch, such as Xamarin (formerly known as MonoTouch) are permitted. This is also why Flash (even for out-of-browser) is not permitted: because you cannot use Cocoa Touch from within Flash, and the same applies to Silverlight).

If you want to target iOS and use C# and the .NET Framework then this can be done with Xamarin, however you still need to use iOS's UI framework unless you're making a game and you use something like Unity.

Comment: One small note, you can develop ASP.NET websites that will work in the iOS browser, so that may be an option for getting your Microsoft based application onto iOS